# How to use my Canon MP210 with Raspbian

Tags: printing

I have this Canon MP210 and I would like to turn it to wireless printing and scanning using raspberry.

I've installed CUPS (apt-get install cups) and I can find the MP210 in the drivers' list.

If I print a test page it won't print.

So I've investigated further and it looks like Canon used to provide the linux driver (cnijfilter-mp210series_2.80-1_i386.deb) I've downloaded and extracted from it simply the ppd file, deleted the printer in CUPS and installed a brand new one with the ppd file.

No luck: the test page is not printed anyway.

(I have an error with missing /usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocanonij)

I've also found a few forums where they suggested to use mp160 drivers or mp180: no luck at all.

What can I try?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The printer was working from the start but using SAMBA to print it had probably some problem.

I've found here a perfectly working solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/110727/windows-computers-can-only-print-test-pages-to-shared-ubuntu-printer

I copy and paste it anyway:

> In Linux stop sharing the printer through Samba.
>
> Share it through CUPS instead: go to `http://servername:631/` and there
>   will be spoe "Share printers" checkbox.
>
> On Windows add a Network printer, and don't search for it; add
>   manually this address:
>
> `http://servername_or_IP:631/printers/printer_name`
>
> printer_name is the name shown in the CUPS Web interface for your
>   printer.
>
> You will be prompted to choose the proper model and a driver will be
>   installed. That's it.
>
> Unlike Samba, advanced feature also work now.